# Returning the code of GeoServer REST parametric

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-api

I want to return my code Python of GeoServer REST API parametric. How can I do that?

```
# Import the library

from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver

# Initialize the library

Password = 'geoserver'
UserName = 'admin'
workspace_name= 'test'
DB_name= 'dbTest'
Pg_Password= 'ikram'
table_name = 'regions'


geo = Geoserver('http://127.0.0.1:7070/geoserver', username= UserName, password= Password)

# For creating workspace
#geo.create_workspace(workspace='ehtp')

# For uploading raster data to the geoserver
#geo.create_coveragestore(layer_name='regions', path=r'C:\regions\regions.shp', workspace='ehtp')
# For creating postGIS connection and publish postGIS table
geo.create_featurestore(store_name='postgis', workspace= workspace_name, db=DB_name, host='127.0.0.1', pg_user='postgres',
                        pg_password=Pg_Password)
geo.publish_featurestore(workspace= workspace_name, store_name='postgis', pg_table= table_name)   
print("shp added succefuly")
```

Comment: what is a "parametric"?

Comment: what i mean is to return for example the password, the username and the name of the table unknown , it depends to the user of my application. i  hope you understand me.